# "__c" after variables (Python)

Tags: sql, salesforce

Please could anyone explain me which is the meaning of adding __c at the end of some variables? What is the difference from not adding this "__c"?

```
SELECT
           Id,
           Type,
           Name,
           Owner.Full_Name__c,
           Language__c,
           Account_Type__c,
           Account_Status__c,
    
    FROM Accounts
```

I'm selecting some fields from a Salesforce table.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28708/difference-between-c-and-r

Comment: @ryyker the question you have linked is irrelevant. Notice it is about Python variable names, and not SQL column names in Salesforce.

Comment: @user253751 -   I'm confused.   I was looking at the OP title, which explicitly implies Python variables.  But clearly I can see in the body of the question that OP has evidently referred to field names in a table, not python variable names.   Hmmm.  I guess I should remove the close vote...  This question has different problems.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you, I think I found it. Just in Setup > ObjectManager > Account > FieldsAndRelationships. The fact is that in Salesforce each variable it's defined in a way. Ex: Account Type --> Files Name = Account_Type__c.